# Big-theta runtime of two linear nested loops, the inner running half as many times for each iteration of the outer.

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity

I'm having a lot of trouble with this algorithms problem. I'm supposed to find a big-theta analysis of the following algorithm:

```
function example(n):
    int j=n
    for i=0;i<n;i++:
        doSomethingA()
        for k=0;k<=j;k++:
            doSomethingB()
        j/=2
```

My approach is to break the entire execution of the algorithm into two parts. One part where doSomethingA() and doSomethingB() are both called, and the second part after j becomes 0 and only doSomethingA() is called until the program halts.

With this approach, you have part 1 occurring for Logn iterations of the outer loop, part 2 occurring for n-logn iterations of the outer loop.

The number of times the inner loop runs is halved for each run, so in total the number of times it runs should be [2n-1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20n*2%5E(-i),%20i%3D0%20to%20log(2,n)).  So the runtime for part 1 should be (2n-1)*c, a constant. I'm not entirely sure if this is valid

For part 2, the work inside the loop is always constant, and the loop repeats (n-logn) times.

So we have ((2n-1)+(n-logn))*c

I'm not sure whether the work I've done up to here is correct, nor am I certain how to continue. My intuition tells me this is O(n), but I'm not sure how to rationalize that in big-theta. Beyond that it's possible my entire approach is flawed. How should I attack a question like this? If my approach is valid, how should I complete it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's "Big O" no thetas :) Also "Big O" is just the notation (widely used in math): what you are analysing is the time complexity.

Comment: I'm confused. Big-O and Big-Theta are different concepts no? I've been asked to find Big-Theta, not Big-O.

Comment: Yes, O and Theta are different concepts. Theta is the same as (O and Omega). Roughly O is kind of an upper bound, Omega kind of a lower bound and therefore Theta is the exact same asymptotic behavior.

Comment: My bad: I had completely forgot that actually existed - too many years away from academia I guess :-)

Comment: The inner loop will at least run once during each iteration of the outer loop (even when j has reached 0, it will run once)

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to investigate how often `doSomethingA` and `doSomethingB` is executed.

For `doSomethingA` it is clearly n times.

For `doSomethingB` we get (n+1) + (n/2+1) + (n/4+1) + ... + 1 so roughly 2n + n. The 2n from the n+n/2+n/4+... and the n from summing up the 1s.

All together we get O(n) and also Theta(n) since you need at least Omega(n) as can be seen from the n times `doSomethingA` is executed.